# how to add different JComponent to JPanel in vertical mode with different alignment?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

I have a JPanel(which has scrollbar) and I want to add some JTextPans and JPanel dynamically to it. and represent them in vertical mode
I have try BoxLayout.Y_AXIS, but the problem is it respects the component's maximum size. and when I add more JComponent their size become smaller in way that their content is not viewable.

how can I make BoxLayout respects the component's correct size (fix one), or is there another solution to represent different component in vertical mode i jpanel?

Answer (score 0):

You can override

```
public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container target)
```

method of BoxLayout to return preferredLayoutSize()

OR

You can override getMinimumSize() method of all the added component to return getPreferedSize()

OR

choose another layout manager - e.g. GridBagLayout

Comment: how can I override methods?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm

Comment: I override minimumLayoutSize : chatPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(chatPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS){
   /**
    * 
    */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   Override
   public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container target){
    return new Dimension(100, 10);
   }
   
  }); and getMinimumSize(): JTextPane receive = new JTextPane(){
   /**
    * 
    */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   Override
   public Dimension getMinimumSize(){
    return getPreferredSize();
   }
  }; but it is same as befor!